# Excel - How to count unique records with specified condition in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table like following:

[image]

And I want to count for each store, how many bills purchased single Item ? How many purchased 2 and full set of items ? The result should look like below

[image]

Where in store 'm3', bill 300 bought 2 item C but only count for 1 in the final result. This is where I struggle with, since I tried
`COUNTIFS(A:A, "=m1", B:B, "=A")` (then add with count for B and C) to get single item for store m1 but unable to figure out how to distinguish with the unique bill numbers.

Please don't mind asking if needed more clarifications, and I do prefer excel in-built functions rather than VBA.

Comment: What is the logic for Single column? for example for the case of m1 and m2

Comment: @DavidLeal if the bill consists of only A or B or C items then it is considered Single. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, but m1 has A and B but it is considered a single

Comment: @DavidLeal it also uses the Bill Number to denote different groupings.  So M1 has two bills.  One that is single(`100`) and the other that has `A` and `B`(`101`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Office 365 formula we start with the basic formula to find the singles:

```
=BYROW(E2:E4,
    LAMBDA(z,SUM(--(
        BYROW(--(COUNTIFS(A:A,z,C:C,UNIQUE($C$2:$C$8),B:B,{"A","B","C"})>0),
            LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))=1))))
```

This will give you the single results:

[image]

The others are all variations of that formula:

A,B

```
=BYROW(E2:E4,
    LAMBDA(z,SUM(--(
        BYROW(--(COUNTIFS(A:A,z,C:C,UNIQUE($C$2:$C$8),B:B,{"A","B"})>0),
            LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))=2))))-J2#
```

B,C

```
=BYROW(E2:E4,
    LAMBDA(z,SUM(--(
        BYROW(--(COUNTIFS(A:A,z,C:C,UNIQUE($C$2:$C$8),B:B,{"C","B"})>0),
            LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))=2))))-J2#
```

A,C

```
=BYROW(E2:E4,
    LAMBDA(z,SUM(--(
        BYROW(--(COUNTIFS(A:A,z,C:C,UNIQUE($C$2:$C$8),B:B,{"C","A"})>0),
            LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))=2))))-J2#
```

All

```
=BYROW(E2:E4,
    LAMBDA(z,SUM(--(
        BYROW(--(COUNTIFS(A:A,z,C:C,UNIQUE($C$2:$C$8),B:B,{"A","B","C"})>0),
            LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))=3))))
```

We have to add the `-J2#` to the end of the doubles to remove when it has all three.  It will count in both places.

[image]

With Older Versions of Excel we need to do some gymnastics with SUMPRODUCT, MMULT, INDEX, MODE.MULT, etc

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    --(MMULT(
        --(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,C:C,INDEX(C:C,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH($C$2:$C$8,C:C,0)=ROW($C$2:$C$8),ROW($C$2:$C$8)*{1,1}))))),B:B,{"A","B","C"})>0),
        {1;1;1})=1))
```

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    --(MMULT(
        --(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,C:C,INDEX(C:C,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH($C$2:$C$8,C:C,0)=ROW($C$2:$C$8),ROW($C$2:$C$8)*{1,1}))))),B:B,{"A","B"})>0),
        {1;1})=2))-J2
```

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    --(MMULT(
        --(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,C:C,INDEX(C:C,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH($C$2:$C$8,C:C,0)=ROW($C$2:$C$8),ROW($C$2:$C$8)*{1,1}))))),B:B,{"B","C"})>0),
        {1;1})=2))-J2
```

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    --(MMULT(
        --(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,C:C,INDEX(C:C,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH($C$2:$C$8,C:C,0)=ROW($C$2:$C$8),ROW($C$2:$C$8)*{1,1}))))),B:B,{"A","C"})>0),
        {1;1})=2))-J2
```

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    --(MMULT(
        --(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,C:C,INDEX(C:C,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH($C$2:$C$8,C:C,0)=ROW($C$2:$C$8),ROW($C$2:$C$8)*{1,1}))))),B:B,{"A","B","C"})>0),
        {1;1;1})=3))
```

Each of these would be placed in the first row of their respective columns and confirmed as array formula by using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

They they would be dragged/copied down the columns.

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth answer. Although in my actual task, I only need to distinguish combination of 2 product category but out of my curiosity, I do notice that if a bill consists of a full item packages, your solution also take it into accounted for A+B, B+C and C+A. Any way to resolve this may I ask ?

Comment: We can use REDUCE to loop through the headers: 
`=LET(header,{"Single","A + B","B + C","C + A","Full"},DROP(REDUCE(0,header,LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,BYROW(E2:E4,
    LAMBDA(z,SUM(--(
        BYROW(--(COUNTIFS(A:A,z,C:C,UNIQUE($C$2:$C$8),B:B,CHOOSE(XMATCH(y,header),{"A","B","C"},{"A","B"},{"B","C"},{"C","A"},{"A","B","C"}))>0),
            LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))=CHOOSE(XMATCH(y,header),1,2,2,2,3)))))))),,1))`

Comment: @241ringgit Add a `-J2#` to the two sequence ones for the first formula group and `-J2` to the second.  I will edit in a moment.  It will subtract any that are full.

Answer (score 2):

Here, another alternative that generates the entire output for all cases with one formula. Use the following formula in cell `E2`:

```
=LET(ms, UNIQUE(A2:A8), ux, UNIQUE(A2:C8), CALC, LAMBDA(arr,cnt, BYROW(ms,
  LAMBDA(m, LET(subset, CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(ux, INDEX(ux,,1)=m),2,3),
   C, INDEX(subset,,2), SUM(BYROW(MMULT(IF(TOROW(C)=UNIQUE(C),1,0),
   TRANSPOSE(IF(TOROW(INDEX(subset,,1))=arr,1,0))),
   LAMBDA(r, N(SUM(r)=cnt)))))))),
  HSTACK(ms, CALC({"A";"B";"C"}, 1), CALC({"A";"B"},2), CALC({"B";"C"},2),
    CALC({"C";"A"},2), CALC({"A";"B";"C"}, 3)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

We create a user `LAMBDA` function `CALC` with input argument `arr` (items values) and `cnt` (count condition to check), so we can generate all possible output changing the input parameters via `HSTACK` function.

`CALC` uses `ux` name, that represents the input removing duplicated row, such as the combination: `{m3,C,300}`. Now we cannot use [RACON functions](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions), because we need to work with an array, therefore in order to do the count for **Item** and **Bill** column values, we use `MMULT` function combined with `IF` statement as follow:

```
MMULT(IF(TOROW(C)=UNIQUE(C),1,0),TRANSPOSE(IF(TOROW(INDEX(subset,,1))=arr,1,0))
```

The output of `MMULT`, on each row (unique bill numbers) has the occurrences of each `arr` value. Therefore if we do the sum by row (inner `BYROW`) and check against the number of counts we are looking for (`cnt`), we get the expected counts we are looking for.

The rest is just to invoke `CALC` for all cases and append by column via `HSTACK`.

Comment: very nice use of LAMBDA!

Comment: for fun `=LET(ms,UNIQUE(A2:A8),ux,UNIQUE(A2:C8),hdr,{"Single","A + B","B + C","C + A","Full"},chdr,{"A + B + C","A + B","B + C","C + A","A + B + C"},CALC,LAMBDA(arr,cnt,BYROW(ms,
LAMBDA(m,LET(subset,CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(ux,INDEX(ux,,1)=m),2,3),
C,INDEX(subset,,2),SUM(BYROW(MMULT(IF(TOROW(C)=UNIQUE(C),1,0),
TRANSPOSE(IF(TOROW(INDEX(subset,,1))=arr,1,0))),
LAMBDA(r,N(SUM(r)=cnt)))))))),
VSTACK(HSTACK("Store ID",hdr),
REDUCE(ms,SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(hdr)),LAMBDA(_ms,_sq,LET(ts,TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(chdr,_sq),," + "),cnt,IF(INDEX(hdr,,_sq)="Single",1,COUNTA(ts)),HSTACK(_ms,CALC(ts,cnt)))))))`

Comment: yes, I was having a similar idea to generalize the process taking the letter information from the header, but I didn't finish it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, we could even wrote something to get all combinations of 2 dynamically, starting with "Single" and ending with "Full", but that's overkill.